# Madeira - transport to Levada das 25 Fontes

Tags: public-transport, portugal, hitchhiking, madeira

I will be going to Madeira for a few days in May with my friend. We would love to go for the hike Levada das 25 Fontes. Unfortunately I don't see any public transport going to the starting point of the trail.

What options do we have? Taking a taxi from Estrela da Calheta? How much would it cost? Or maybe try to hitch-hike? How feasible is hitch-hiking on Madeira?

Renting a car is not an option for us as we don't have driver's license.

Comment: As far as I have read the Lonely Planet guide on Madeira, there should be organised hiking tours for most of the _famous_ PR routes. Try to contact local tourist agencies and find out whether there are any such tours during your stay.

Comment: We are not really interested in guided tours but this might still be a good way to get there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Calheta to the track is around 7 kms, so taxi should not be more than 15€. 
You can easily hitch-hike, other option is carsharing with fellow hikers that can drive.